# Regexp match everything after a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the base64 string from a data-url. The string looks like this, so I am trying to extract everything after the word base64

```
test = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB'
```

So I want to extract the following from the above string

```
,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB
```

Here is my regex

```
const base64rgx = new RegExp('(?<=base64)(?s)(.*$)');
console.log(test.match(base64rgx))
```

But this fails with the error:

```
 VM3616:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=base64)(?s)(.*$)/: Invalid group
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var test = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB';

var regex = /(?<=base64).+/;

var r = test.match(regex);

console.log(r);
```

Here's the regex: https://regex101.com/r/uzyu0a/1

Comment: I'm happy to help

Comment: Helped me to solve my issue too. Thanks Alex.

Comment: This fails in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that lookbehinds are not being supported.  But the good news is that you don't need a lookaround here, the following pattern should work:

```js
test = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB'
var regex = /.*?base64(.*?)/g;
var match = regex.exec(test);
console.log(match[1]);
```

I'm not sure precisely how much of the string after `base64` you want to capture.  If, for example, you don't want the comma, or the `9j` portion, then we can easily modify the pattern to handle that.

Comment: When i run this a couple of times i get null and then results alternatively. Do you know why this could be with the exec?

Comment: @Rookie You need to tell me what data you are running this against?  Is it more than one line of data?  For a single base 64 string I think my answer should work fine.

Comment: It is a data-url so the data is multi line, I posted the cropped version of the base64 string to illustrate the problem..

Comment: @Rookie Try using lazy dot `.*`

Comment: For me the accepted answer gave all the words before the given word together with the word itself. This one worked correctly